# WooComerce: How to change header text for in the shopping cart

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, cart

How to change header text for the cart ?

I change it in the `woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php` but doesn't work. I mean header items eg. from 'product' to 'service', from 'quantity' to 'quantity of people' ,.. .

It's totally strange even I try to delete /cart/cart.php but nothing change site also working, it looks that woocommerce doesn't use cart.php? 
I think problem won't be in the cache because I try another browser and same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What theme (or child theme) are you using?

Normally you don't have to change the woocommerce templates inside the plugin itself, because when plugin get updated the templates will be replaced with original ones.

The good way is to copy the `templates` folder (located inside the woocommerce plugin folder) to your active child theme or theme. Once done, **you have to rename** this `templates` folder: `woocommerce`. Otherwise the templates will not be enabled.

So the cart.php template path in your theme is : `woocommerce/cart/cart.php` but not `woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php`…

See [Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)